# Wgpu: correctly written WGSL shader parsing error

Tags: rust, shader, wgpu-rs

I am using wgpu-rs and writing shaders in WGSL. To test an example shader, I copied some sample code from here: https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#var-and-let.

Here is my simple shader:

```
// Vertex shader

struct VertexInput {
    [[location(0)]] pos: vec3<f32>;
};

struct VertexOutput {
    [[builtin(position)]] pos: vec4<f32>;
};

[[stage(vertex)]]
fn main(vertex_input: VertexInput) -> VertexOutput {
    var out: VertexOutput;
    out.pos = vec4<f32>(vertex_input.pos, 1.0);

    var a: i32 = 2;
    var i: i32 = 0;
    loop {
        if (i >= 4) { break; }
    
        let step: i32 = 1;
    
        i = i + step;
        if (i % 2 == 0) { continue; }
    
        a = a * 2;
    }

    return out;
}

// Fragment shader

[[stage(fragment)]]
fn main(in: VertexOutput) -> [[location(0)]] vec4<f32> {
    return vec4<f32>(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

However, when I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
[2021-08-18T16:13:33Z ERROR wgpu_core::device] Failed to parse WGSL code for Some("Shader: simple shader"): expected '(', found ';'
[2021-08-18T16:13:33Z ERROR wgpu::backend::direct] wgpu error: Validation Error

    Caused by:
        In Device::create_shader_module
          note: label = `Shader: simple shader`
        Failed to parse WGSL
```

The error is caused by the line `i = i + step;`, however as mentioned before this snippet of code was copied from the W3 documentation so why doesn't it compile?

Comment: Hmm, `step()` is a [built-in function](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#float-builtin-functions), what happens if you name it something different?

Comment: Not saying the code is wrong. The docs say that identifier shadowing is allowed as long as they're different scopes ([link](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#declaration-and-scope)). It could be a problem with wgpu-rs.

Comment: @kmdreko I changed the name of the variable and it works now. Thanks a lot! (I if you post your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the `wgpu-rs` shader validation is favoring the [built-in `step()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#float-builtin-functions) over a variable declared with the same name. Going by the W3 WGSL docs, this [should resolve to the variable](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#declaration-and-scope) since it is in a closer scope.

Renaming the `step` variable to something else should fix the immediate problem.

There is already [an issue](https://github.com/gfx-rs/naga/issues/1046) created to track this, but I've added this as another example.